# Cannot access array of a custom class

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I keep getting the error message "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this:

listOfBanks[0].Deposit(50);

and

accntBlnce.text = "Account Balance:\n" + listOfBanks[curBank].GetBalance().ToString("c");

I have 3 options listed in the drop down menu and when I Debug.Log the number of items in the array I get 3 as my count. But I can't do anything with them. The banks variable is set as the Dropdown object in the inspector as well as the accntBlnce as the text object in my panel.

The code is below.

Banks.cs

```
public class Banks : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dropdown banks;
    public Text accntBlnce;
    public Bank[] listOfBanks;
    public int curBank = 0;

    void Start() {
        listOfBanks = new Bank[banks.options.Count];
        listOfBanks[0].Deposit(50);
    }

    void Update() {
        curBank = banks.value;
        accntBlnce.text = "Account Balance:\n" + listOfBanks[curBank].GetBalance().ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Bank.cs

```
public class Bank{

    public Bank() { }

    public Bank(string orgn, float amntToRprt, float blnce) {
        origin = orgn;
        amountToReport = amntToRprt;
        balance = blnce;
    }

    public string origin { get; set; }
    public float amountToReport { get; set; }
    public float balance { get; set; }

    public bool Deposit(float amnt) {
        if (amnt > 0) {
            balance += amnt;
            if(amnt > amountToReport) {
                FlagForReport();
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void FlagForReport() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public float GetBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public bool Withdraw(float amnt) {
        if (amnt > 0) {
            if (balance >= amnt) {
                balance -= amnt;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public bool Transfer(float amnt, Bank bank) {
        if (amnt > 0) {
            if (balance >= amnt) {
                if(bank.Deposit(amnt))
                    balance -= amnt;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fourth time array question is asked this week with the-same problem and the-same solution.

You declared the array here:

```
listOfBanks = new Bank[banks.options.Count];
```

but you did not create new instance of each Bank script before calling

`listOfBanks[0].Deposit(50);` and `listOfBanks[curBank].GetBalance().ToString("c").`

Declaring array and setting the size is **NOT** the-same as creating new instance of a script.

The solution is to loop through the array and create new instance of each one.

In your `Banks.cs`, replace the code in your `Start()` function with the one below:

```
void Start()
{
    //Declare how much Bank array should be created
    listOfBanks = new Bank[banks.options.Count];

    //Now Create instance of each bank
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfBanks.Length; i++)
    {
        //Create new instance of each Bank class
        //listOfBanks[i] = new Bank();
        listOfBanks[i] = new Bank("", 50, 50);
    }

    listOfBanks[0].Deposit(50);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was typing this out as I received your response, I feel dumb. Its been so long since I last programmed. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: @The_Guy No. People will learn from it. Anyone who googles Unity array null stuff will likely come across these. It prevents more people from asking the-same question again.